# Exchange server: outgoing SMTP server name?

Tags: active-directory, smtp, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to find the name of the SMTP server responsible for delivering outgoing Exchange messages.

I can easily find the incoming SMTP server name though the MX record, but I need the SMTP server for the outgoing messages.  Autodiscover does not help either - it has everything and a kitchen sink (EWS endpoint, etc.), but not the outgoing SMTP server name.

Is it in the Active Directory (for the on-prem Exchange servers)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Exchange are you running?

You can run the following from an Exchange Management Shell, it should provide you with sufficient information.

```
Get-SendConnector | Select-Object -Property Identity,Enabled,SmartHosts,AddressSpaces,SourceTransportServers
```

Or from the ECP/EAC, select mail flow, and then select Send Connectors.  If you have more than one, you'll have to poke around and find the one that is enabled, for the address space '*' with the lowest cost - that will most likely be your default connector.  Open/view the send connector.  Select Scoping, on the bottom half of the popup window, you will see a "Source server" box.  The server(s) in that box are those responsible for getting outbound email out of the Exchange organization.

However, there is a possibility that Exchange just sends to a smart host which scans, logs or otherwise handles your outbound mail before it actually leaves your network.  There would be an entry under "SmartHosts" if that were the case in the powershell output or under "Delivery" in the EAC.

As a side note, there is no real de facto "outbound smtp" server like there is a de facto "inbound smtp server" (i.e the MX).  I think about as close as you can get is to have a name, address, or block designated in your SPF record, but its not quite the same thing.

Edit - find information in Active Directory:

```
Get-ADObject -Filter 'objectClass -eq "msExchRoutingSMTPConnector" -SearchBase "CN=Configuration,DC=domain,dc=com"
```

Will give you a list of send connectors, the routingList Attribute will tell you what namespace each connector is valid for and what the cost is.  Unfortunately, from these objects, I do not know how to obtain the server names included in those send connectors.

You could also find these via ADSIedit or another tool that would allow you to browse the configuration in AD.  The rough path is:

```
CN=Connections,CN=ExchangeRouting Group (xxxxxx),CN=RoutingGroups,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (xxxxxx),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=ExchangeOrganization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=com".
```

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: This is assuming I have access to the Exchange Management Shell :-( I need to do this from a client side - is this information stored in AD? Also, isn't Get-SendConnector Exchange 2016 only?

Comment: Get-SendConnector has been around since 2007.

Comment: Even if I didn't, I did provide a means of accessing the information via the ECP/EAC (Exchange 2010+).  As to my other assumptions, you provided no restrictions as to _how_ the information had to be accessed, so I naturally assumed that it was an Administrator of some kind seeking that information.  Aside from that, I'm don't believe this information is furnished to the Outlook client, as it doesn't need this information in an Exchange environment, as (when connected to Exchange) Outlook doesn't actually send emails via SMTP.

Comment: I understand that, but I was hoping that information is externally accessible. It looks like there a "CN=SMTP Receiver Connector" object in AD exposed by its parent  Exchange server. Would that be useable?

Comment: The SMTP Receive connector is exactly that, a receive connector. That would be how inbound mail _enters_ the organization (the server that responds as the MX).  Are you looking to have the actual internal server name (hostname) of one or more Exchange servers to be exposed publicly/externally?  I've seen that before - when somebody doesn't take the appropriate steps to scrub it from outbound emails.  Generally, you want that information _not_ to leave your network.  Why don't you back up a step and explain why you're looking for the internal servername?  You may get a better answer.

Comment: I assumed that the default "Client Frontend <Server name>" connector is for the authenticated SMTP connections on port 587?

Comment: It _could_ be.  You can have multiple receive connectors; each for different things, listening on different ports, accepting mail from different IPs, using different forms of authentication, etc..  Again, if you can back up a step and explain why you're looking for this particular information.  What are you trying to accomplish that leads you to believe that you need to know the server name of one (or more) servers that send outbound email from your organization?

Comment: I am trying to reduce the number of parameters the end user must provide - one of them is the SMTP server name. This is for a product of mine called Proxy Manager - http://www.dimastr.com/proxyman/

Comment: If its Outlook sending the email, SMTP isn't actually used.  But it looks like your product may actually be using SMTP though, so I see why you would want; and understand now why you would have been looking at a receive connector.  To ensure your product worked in all Exchange environments, you would need a program to list out all receive connectors, their authentication mechanisms, permission groups and remote network ranges, then logically choose the right one for your client based upon its current IP.

Comment: And (just thinking about it), the problem with that approach is that viewing the configuration of any/all receive connectors requires that the user be granted the Exchange View-Only Administrators role.  That's probably more complicated than just asking somebody for the right server name.